# storing bitmap in integer array

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

what is the best way to do this. i have an array of height*width in length. do i simply loop through bitmap setting each pixel to the array based on the loop index? thanks

[update]
It's an app that places a fisheye distortion on a bitmap. i'm trying to store the pixel data in an array opposed to calling Bitmap.setPixel() as this comes with a massive GC overhead

```
 for (int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++) {
        for (int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++) {
            origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);
            getRadXStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);
            float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);
            sampleImage(input,x,y);

            color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
        //  System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

            //if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 150 ){
            if (Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) <= 22500 ) {
                // dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                arr[i]=color;
            } else {
                //dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
                arr[i]=origPixel;
            }
        }
    }

Bitmap dst2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(arr,width,height,input.getConfig());
        return dst2;
```

Comment: What's the sample code showing us? Where are you setting pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the method [getPixels(...) on Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)?

Comment: hi i think you just missed my update. the set/getPixel from Bitmap comes with a large  GC overhead. it takes around 50 seconds to transform image. this is due to gc performed. i've run traceview and it's the bitmap set/getPixel that i need to avoid

Comment: I am not talking about the method to getPixel(...), I am talking about getPixels(...) (note the 's') which will load all the pixel color data into an int[].  Is this not what you are after?  Where is this GC overhead you are talking about?

Comment: ah sorry for missing your point. yes i'll try that as there's only on call to bitmap class. thanks

Comment: actually i don't think i can use this as i need to loop through the bitmap to apply the effect. it's the setting of the pixels in the destination bitmap that carries the overhead with setPixel(). if i could write the pixel data to an array instead of making that call tp bitmap setPixel then the app would speed up. i'd just pass the array to the bitmap static createBitmap()

Answer (score 0):

To fill it, you will have to loop through the Bitmap to set each pixel.  That said, I don't know if you'll see a major performance increase.

Comment: @haphazard hi, why 3 arrays? isn't the color of each pixel stored as an int value?

Comment: @haphazard the method samleImage plays a part in distorting the image and dosn't make alot of calls to the bitmap setters/getters. It's these calls that effect GC i think. The app runs fine apart from when the bitmap is displayed i think only the top row of pixels are shown the rest of bitmap is black. i think it's how i input the pixels into the array or something or looping prob

Comment: @turtleboy the GC is only called when objects are created and then de-referenced.  Assuming a Bitmap object is actually stored as a bunch of ints, it is effectively doing what you want to do with your array.

Comment: @haphazard hi, i've got it down to 15 seconds by using the array, i think that dst.setPixel in turn calls or check alot of other things. i watched a google vid that describes how bitmaps are stored on native layer and the overhead involved. i'm in process of using an overlay with the effect on, it needs tweeking put the app processes the bitmap in 6 secs now, just thought i'd update and thanks